# Django 1.11 Horizontal choice field

Tags: django

I've just updated from Django 1.10 to 1.11.1. 
In my template `new_house_edit.html` I have the following:

`{{ form.rating }}`

`models.py` contain the following:

```
class NewHouse(models.Model):
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=(
                                    (1, "1"),
                                    (2, "2"),
                                    (3, "3"),
                                    (4, "4"),
                                    (5, "5"),
                                    ),
                                    default=3
                            )
```

In `forms.py` I used to have the following:

```
class HorizontalRadioRenderer(forms.RadioSelect.renderer):
    def render(self):
        return mark_safe(u'\n'.join([u'%s\n' % w for w in self]))

class NewHouseForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = NewHouse
        fields = (
                'rating',)
        widgets={
                "rating": forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer),
                }
```

Which gave the following error `AttributeError: type object 'RadioSelect' has no attribute 'renderer'.` I tried to solve it by doing this which is not working:

```
class HorizontalRadioSelect(forms.RadioSelect):
    template_name = 'new_house_edit'


class NewHouseForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = NewHouse
        fields = (
                'rating',)
        widgets={
                "rating": "rating": forms.ChoiceField(widget=HorizontalRadioSelect, choices=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)),
                }
```

I now get the error `AttributeError: 'ChoiceField' object has no attribute 'use_required_attribute'`. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Tim Graham has answered a relevant question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/tlcXfeSVm00), it may help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your second code snippet you pass form field object to widgets dict instead of widget object. So correct code look like:

```
class HorizontalRadioSelect(forms.RadioSelect):
    template_name = 'horizontal_select.html'


class NewHouseForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = NewHouse
        fields = (
                'rating',)
        widgets={
                "rating": HorizontalRadioSelect()
                }
```

In your app directory create templates folder and add horizontal_select.html with following html.

```
{% with id=widget.attrs.id %}
    <ul{% if id %} id="{{ id }}"{% endif %}{% if widget.attrs.class %} class="{{ widget.attrs.class }}"{% endif %}>
        {% for group, options, index in widget.optgroups %}
            {% if group %}
                <li>{{ group }}
                <ul{% if id %} id="{{ id }}_{{ index }}"{% endif %}>
            {% endif %}
            {% for option in options %}
                <li style="display: inline-block">{% include option.template_name with widget=option %}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            {% if group %}
                </ul>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thanks. It removed the attribute error but gave me a new error related to the template name. I was giving the name of the template where I was using the rating. I think this is incorrect. What should the template_name refer to?

Comment: Was hard but finally i could do it: using the two template options.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is quite an old question but having spent some time today trying the different methods in various threads (after upgrading from 1.8 to 1.11) here is my solution.

For each radio group, define the following in the template (where "radio_list" is the name of the field):

```
{% for radio in radio_list %}
    {{ radio }}
{% endfor %}
```

This is it at its simplest. Easy eh? You can basically apply any styling you want. It's all in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect) in the RadioSelect section.

The moral of this little tale? Read the docs. Django is probably the best-documented app I have ever worked with. If I had done it earlier it would have saved me a lot of wasted time today when I could have been doing something more interesting.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @isedwards - Thanks for the edit. I had missed that.

Answer (score 2):

First, [ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) is not a widget - it is a [Form Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/).

So, change your form,

```
class NewHouseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    CHOICES = ((1, "1"),
               (2, "2"),
               (3, "3"),
               (4, "4"),
               (5, "5"))

    rating = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES,
       widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'radio-inline'}),
       )

    class Meta:
        model = NewHouse
        fields = (
            'rating',)
```

Then in your customised radio-select `template_name` should be the path to the template which is you are using.
If the template resides under your app_level "templates" subdirectory or in your project-level "templates" sub-directory, you could just do like below.

```
class HorizontalRadioSelect(forms.RadioSelect):
    template_name = 'new_house_edit.html'
```

If its under another subdirectory under the "templates" sub-directory then you need to specify the path to the template.

Django as default check for templates in "templates" sub-directory in each apps of your project.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, but it displays a dropdown menu instead of the horizontal radio select. The template is in a subfolder called "app" in the "templates" subdirectory. So I did this: template_name = 'app\templates\app\new_house_edit.html'

Comment: OK, but I still have the same issue. It's displaying a dropdown menu with the choices instead of the horizontal radio select.

Comment: Its because your custom radio select is not rendering. Drop down is the default widget. try setting the choices as in your models. I have updated the answer for your reference.

Comment: Updated the answer.. try it

Comment: OK, I added HorizontalRadioRenderer back in and now get "AttributeError: type object 'RadioSelect' has no attribute 'renderer'"

Comment: what's your django version?

Comment: It's version 1.11.1. I didn't have this problem in 1.10.

Comment: Fuller error "class HorizontalRadioRenderer(forms.RadioSelect.renderer):
AttributeError: type object 'RadioSelect' has no attribute 'renderer'"

Comment: Its because, the renderer function is broken in django 1.11, I ve found a hack around, add class "inline" to the radio select widget... updated the code

Comment: Nice. I'm getting a radio select now, but the choices are display vertically - not horizontally.

Comment: have you added the class attribute like in my answer?

Comment: I feel bad for taking so much of your time - but it's still vertically.